# Raspberry Pi webserver cant read php files after phpmyadmin install

Tags: phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

After instillation of myphpadmin PHP files display this error

This page isn’t working
(Domain Name) is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Also when attempting to install or up date php-7.0 i get the errors

E: Unable to locate package php-7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php-7.0'

Comment: Made the directory both readable (r) and executable (x) by all users. sudo chmod o+xr /var/www. Now the PHP is loaded but the page is empty.

Comment: Specifically the browser is commenting out the PHP. PHP 5 is installed and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use PhpMyAdmin now you have to have php version 5.5 or higher installed

to install php version 7.0 you have to do the folowing steps : 
open sources.list : `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

add these lines to file:

```
deb http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

then exit nano and run this command (`ctrl+X` then `y` and then `Enter`) : `sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key CCD91D6111A06851`

also run this command: `sudo gpg --armor --export CCD91D6111A06851 | sudo apt-key add -`

PhpMyAdmin also requires MySql 
run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server python-mysqldb`

run `sudo apt-get update`